# Copy and pasting to a template and saving as new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to loop through and paste each different group of IDs into a template I have in a separate workbook. I then want it to save as a new workbook, using the Vendor Name in C1 of the second sheet in the new workbook.

But there's a few problems in me trying to complete this;

1. It is giving me an error at the SaveAs line.
2. The filename is not pulling from the cell I want.
3. It stops after the first loop.

Anybody have any ideas of what I need to fix?

Here is my current macro:

```
Option Explicit

SubNewBillback()

Dim wsBData, wsBackup, wsCreditMemo As Worksheet
Dim wb, wbTemplate, wbAllRebates As Workbook
Dim rngHeader As Range
Dim i As Long, n As Long, LastRow As Long, StartRow As Long
Dim InvNum, InvDate, VendName, VendNum, strPath, FileName, openfile As String
Dim Amt As Integer
       
strPath = "\\Billback Data Base-Spreadsheet\2021\September\Excel\"
openfile = "\\Billback Data Base-Spreadsheet\2021\September\BillbackAutoTemplate.xlsx"

Set wbAllRebates = ActiveWorkbook
With wbAllRebates
    Set wsBData = .Sheets("BackupData")
    Set wsBackup = .Sheets("Backup")
End With
'copy data from query
wsBData.Cells.Copy
wsBackup.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

StartRow = 2
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'searches for change in ID#
With wsBackup
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngHeader = .Range("A1:O1")
    For i = 2 To LastRow
       ' change ID next row
       If .Cells(i, "A") <> .Cells(i + 1, "A") Then
           ' create new workbook
           Set wbTemplate = Workbooks.Open(openfile)
           
           .Range("A" & StartRow & ":O" & i).Copy wbTemplate.Sheets(2).Range("A2")
           
           wbTemplate.SaveAs FileName:=strPath & Sheets(2).Cells(i, "C") & ".xlsx"
           
           wbTemplate.Close True
           
           ' move to next
           StartRow = i + 1
           n = n + 1
       End If
    Next
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox n & " billbacks created."
```

End Sub

Comment: I don't think your line `wbTemplate.SaveAs FileName:=strPath & Sheets(2).Cells(i, "C") & ".xlsx"`  is correct.  `.Cells(i,"C")` will return a reference to that cell object.  try adding `.Value` after `.Cells(i,"C")` and see what happens

Comment: @GlennG - the `.Value` is implicit. Good to be explicit about it, but it won't change anything. Most likely the value in that cell contains an invalid character for a filepath.

Comment: `Sheets(2).Cells(i, "C")` is unqualified. Did you mean to have a `.` in front of it?

Comment: @BigBen I added it but got the run-time error "Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: Ah sorry, it needs a workbook qualifier, e.g. `wbTemplate` or `wbAllRebates`, whichever is the proper workbook.

Comment: @GlennG I still get the "SaveAs method of Workbook class failed" run-time error

Comment: What is the result of `Debug.Print strPath & Sheets(2).Cells(i, "C") & ".xlsx"` in the Immediate Window?

Comment: @BigBen debug.print shows the path and the cell value of the first loop, and then blank. is there an error with my loop perhaps?

Comment: Probably you need the appropriate workbook qualifier before `Sheets(2)`.

Comment: @BigBen I added the qualifier before i used debug.print

Comment: Then it is not true that `.Cells(i, "A") <> .Cells(i + 1, "A")`. Perhaps stepping through with F8 might be helpful.

Comment: what is the exact error that it is giving?  have you tried specifying the file type like this? `wbTemplate.SaveAs FileName:=strPath & Sheets(2).Cells(i, "C") & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook`, which workbook is `Sheets(2).Cells(i,"C") & ".xlsx"` supposed to be looking in?

Comment: @GlennG Essentially, I want to open the Template workbook, copy the data chosen, paste it into the second sheet of the Template workbook, and save it as the Vendor Name which is located in C1 after being copied over. It works for the first group of Vendor Name, but then I get an error after that.

Comment: if it works for some and not others, I would have to agree with @BigBen that there is most likely an invalid file name character in the vendor name.

Comment: @GlennG I switched them to test and see if that was it and it worked for the one it previously did not.

Comment: Glad that worked!  I've added an answer with a function that will validate the file name and remove invalid characters

Answer (score 0):

The function at the bottom will remove invalid characters from your file name.  I've added the call to the function in your **Save As** line in your original code.  It will replace any of the following characters in the vendor name   `: \ / ? | * [ ] { } < > ~ " # % &` with a `_`.  If you would rather it replace it with something else just change the `"_"` in the line `sFileName = Replace(sFileName, Mid(vInval, i, 1), "_")` to some other valid character

```
Option Explicit

Sub NewBillback()
    Dim wsBData, wsBackup, wsCreditMemo As Worksheet
    Dim wb, wbTemplate, wbAllRebates As Workbook
    Dim rngHeader As Range
    Dim i As Long, n As Long, LastRow As Long, StartRow As Long
    Dim InvNum, InvDate, VendName, VendNum, strPath, FileName, openfile As String
    Dim Amt As Integer
        strPath = "\\Billback Data Base-Spreadsheet\2021\September\Excel\"
        openfile = "\\Billback Data Base-Spreadsheet\2021\September\BillbackAutoTemplate.xlsx"
        Set wbAllRebates = ActiveWorkbook
        With wbAllRebates
            Set wsBData = .Sheets("BackupData")
            Set wsBackup = .Sheets("Backup")
        End With
'copy data from query
        wsBData.Cells.Copy
        wsBackup.Cells.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        StartRow = 2
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'searches for change in ID#
        With wsBackup
            LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Set rngHeader = .Range("A1:O1")
            For i = 2 To LastRow
' change ID next row
                If .Cells(i, "A") <> .Cells(i + 1, "A") Then
' create new workbook
                    Set wbTemplate = Workbooks.Open(openfile)
                    .Range("A" & StartRow & ":O" & i).Copy wbTemplate.Sheets(2).Range("A2")
                    wbTemplate.SaveAs FileName:=strPath & ValidateFileName(Sheets(2).Cells(i, "C")) & ".xlsx"
                    wbTemplate.Close True
' move to next
                   StartRow = i + 1
                   n = n + 1
                End If
            Next
        End With
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        MsgBox n & " billbacks created."
End Sub

Function ValidateFileName(ByVal sFileName As String) As String
    Dim vInval As String
    Dim i As Long
        vInval = ":\/?|*[]{}<>~""#%&" & Chr(10) & Chr(13)
        For i = 1 To Len(vInval)
             sFileName = Replace(sFileName, Mid(vInval, i, 1), "_")
        Next i
        ValidateFileName = sFileName
End Function
```